# Port accessible only using wget localhost

Tags: node.js, cpanel, whm, configserver

I have a server running centos 7 using cpanel and whm with csf. I am trying to run a nodejs express application on it that listens on port 3000. In order to do so, I added the line `tcp|in|d=3000|s=0.0.0.0` to csf.allow.

When I run the code and use wget localhost:3000, I get the html files as expected, but if I try to connect from a browser the server just doesn't get the request. Am I doingsomehting wrong?

I am new to Linux and server management, so sorry in advance if I didn't give enough information. I'll be happy to provide more if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this from Google, the problem was that my server provider was blocking uncommon ports. I mailed them and after two minutes the problem was solved.